# Is there a way to pass a series as period for Pandas dataframe.shift()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I have a table where I am trying to fill NaN values by incorporating the value at the last month of last year in a calculation. I have an integer month column, so in theory shifting by the month should always give me the last month of last year. But I could not get shift() to work with a series as its period.

The simplest form of the problem is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

#dataframe
start_date = '2022-01-31'
end_date = '2023-12-31'
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='M')

data = {
    'date': dates,
    'year': dates.year,
    'month': dates.month,
    'metric': np.random.randint(1, 15, len(dates))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#for this exercise I want the data in 2023 to be NaN
df.loc[df['year'] == 2023, 'metric'] = np.nan
```

I want to create a new column 'metric_new' where I multiply all values of 2022 by 1.5, and fill NaN values in 2023 by multiplying the last value of metric_new in 2022 by 2.

So, if the metric in 2022-12-31 is 10, metric_new on the same row will be 15, and metric_new in 2023-01-31 and the **entire year 2023** will be 30.

I want this to work if new data is added to the table as well. So metric_new in 2024 should take the last value of itself in 2023 and multiply by 2.

I tried the following simple logic. The idea was to get the 'month' number of lag of the 'metric_new' field. Unfortunately, this does not work.

```
df['metric_new'] = np.where(df['year'] == 2022,
                            1.5*df['metric'],
                            2*df['metric_new'].shift(period = df['month']))
```

The resulting table should look like this:

```
         date  year  month  metric  metric_new
0  2022-01-31  2022      1    13.0        19.5
1  2022-02-28  2022      2     6.0         9.0
2  2022-03-31  2022      3     1.0         1.5
3  2022-04-30  2022      4     4.0         6.0
4  2022-05-31  2022      5    12.0        18.0
5  2022-06-30  2022      6     4.0         6.0
6  2022-07-31  2022      7     8.0        12.0
7  2022-08-31  2022      8    10.0        15.0
8  2022-09-30  2022      9     4.0         6.0
9  2022-10-31  2022     10     6.0         9.0
10 2022-11-30  2022     11     3.0         4.5
11 2022-12-31  2022     12     5.0         7.5
12 2023-01-31  2023      1     NaN         15.0
13 2023-02-28  2023      2     NaN         15.0
14 2023-03-31  2023      3     NaN         15.0
15 2023-04-30  2023      4     NaN         15.0
16 2023-05-31  2023      5     NaN         15.0
17 2023-06-30  2023      6     NaN         15.0
18 2023-07-31  2023      7     NaN         15.0
19 2023-08-31  2023      8     NaN         15.0
20 2023-09-30  2023      9     NaN         15.0
21 2023-10-31  2023     10     NaN         15.0
22 2023-11-30  2023     11     NaN         15.0
23 2023-12-31  2023     12     NaN         15.0
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity? (use `np.random.seed(0)` in the beginning of your code for reproducibility)

Comment: Thanks for the update, Can you add another year to see how 2024 should behave?

Answer (score 0):

`shift()` method expects an integer value for the period parameter, but you're passing a series (`df['month']`) instead. you should do this:

```
df['metric_new'] = np.where(df['year'] == 2022, 1.5 * df['metric'], np.nan)
last_value_2022 = df.loc[df['year'] == 2022, 'metric_new'].iloc[-1]
df.loc[df['year'] == 2023, 'metric_new'] = last_value_2022 * 2
df['metric_new'] = df['metric_new'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Based on your comment:

```
date    year    month   metric  metric_new
0   2022-01-31  2022    1   10.0    15.0
1   2022-02-28  2022    2   9.0 13.5
2   2022-03-31  2022    3   4.0 6.0
3   2022-04-30  2022    4   2.0 3.0
4   2022-05-31  2022    5   7.0 10.5
5   2022-06-30  2022    6   6.0 9.0
6   2022-07-31  2022    7   5.0 7.5
7   2022-08-31  2022    8   1.0 1.5
8   2022-09-30  2022    9   8.0 12.0
9   2022-10-31  2022    10  1.0 1.5
10  2022-11-30  2022    11  2.0 3.0
11  2022-12-31  2022    12  6.0 9.0
12  2023-01-31  2023    1   NaN 18.0
13  2023-02-28  2023    2   NaN 18.0
14  2023-03-31  2023    3   NaN 18.0
15  2023-04-30  2023    4   NaN 18.0
16  2023-05-31  2023    5   NaN 18.0
17  2023-06-30  2023    6   NaN 18.0
18  2023-07-31  2023    7   NaN 18.0
19  2023-08-31  2023    8   NaN 18.0
20  2023-09-30  2023    9   NaN 18.0
21  2023-10-31  2023    10  NaN 18.0
22  2023-11-30  2023    11  NaN 18.0
23  2023-12-31  2023    12  NaN 18.0
```

Comment: Hi Phoenix. Thank you for the answer. 

I think I did not make it clear that I would like the ENTIRE year of 2023 to be a product of last value in 2022 *2. I'll correct my question.

Comment: @Aco Like this?

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic is unclear, but if you want to get the last value per year, multiply it by 1.5, then perform a cumulated product by 2, you can use:

```
df['metric_new'] = df['metric'].mul(1.5)

s = (df
   .sort_values(by=['year', 'month'])
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['year'], keep='last')
   .set_index('year')['metric_new'].fillna(2).cumprod()
)

df.loc[df['metric'].isna(), 'metric_new'] = df['year'].map(s)
```

Output:

```
         date  year  month  metric  metric_new
0  2022-01-31  2022      1    13.0        19.5
1  2022-02-28  2022      2     6.0         9.0
2  2022-03-31  2022      3     1.0         1.5
3  2022-04-30  2022      4     4.0         6.0
4  2022-05-31  2022      5    12.0        18.0
5  2022-06-30  2022      6     4.0         6.0
6  2022-07-31  2022      7     8.0        12.0
7  2022-08-31  2022      8    10.0        15.0
8  2022-09-30  2022      9     4.0         6.0
9  2022-10-31  2022     10     6.0         9.0
10 2022-11-30  2022     11     3.0         4.5
11 2022-12-31  2022     12     5.0         7.5
12 2023-01-31  2023      1     NaN        15.0
13 2023-02-28  2023      2     NaN        15.0
14 2023-03-31  2023      3     NaN        15.0
15 2023-04-30  2023      4     NaN        15.0
16 2023-05-31  2023      5     NaN        15.0
17 2023-06-30  2023      6     NaN        15.0
18 2023-07-31  2023      7     NaN        15.0
19 2023-08-31  2023      8     NaN        15.0
20 2023-09-30  2023      9     NaN        15.0
21 2023-10-31  2023     10     NaN        15.0
22 2023-11-30  2023     11     NaN        15.0
23 2023-12-31  2023     12     NaN        15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your approach is that the `shift` operation doesn't work as you intended. `shift(periods)` will shift the series by the number of periods specified. In your case, you're trying to pass a series (df['month']) as the periods, which doesn't give you the intended result. Instead, you need to find the last value of 'metric_new' for each year and forward fill that value for the NaNs.

Here's a modified version of your approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

# Dataframe
start_date = '2022-01-31'
end_date = '2023-12-31'
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='M')

data = {
    'date': dates,
    'year': dates.year,
    'month': dates.month,
    'metric': np.random.randint(1, 15, len(dates))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# For this exercise, I want the data in 2023 to be NaN
df.loc[df['year'] == 2023, 'metric'] = np.nan

# Multiply all values of 2022 by 1.5
df['metric_new'] = np.where(df['year'] == 2022, 1.5*df['metric'], df['metric'])

# Forward fill 'metric_new' for each year starting from the last month of the previous year
df['metric_new'] = df.groupby((df['year'].shift() != df['year']).cumsum())['metric_new'].ffill()

# For years > 2022, replace 'metric_new' with twice the last value from the previous year
df.loc[df['year'] > 2022, 'metric_new'] = 2 * df.loc[df['year'] == df['year'].unique()[-2], 'metric_new'].values[-1]
```

This script first fills 'metric_new' with 1.5 times 'metric' for 2022, and copies 'metric' values for other years. Then, it forward fills 'metric_new' within each year, starting from the last value of the previous year. Finally, it replaces 'metric_new' values for years greater than 2022 with twice the last 'metric_new' value from 2022. This should give you the desired result.